# Plastic central heating pipe - cover up in built-in cupboard

Tags: water, pipe, central-heating, built-ins

I have a built in cupboard which has plastic water pipes travelling vertically up the inside (supplying a small radiator in the loft). I want to cover them up because they're ugly, awkward and also have flaky paint coming off them, but I don't know if I need to do anything special to prevent condensation, or if I need to consider anything else.

[image: Image of pipes]

I was planning on boxing them up with a couple of battens attached the to wall and some plywood. There are no taps or anything so I'm not planning on making this accessible in the future. I'm then going to fit shelves in the cupboard over them.

Is there anything I should be considering here? Things that come to my mind are condensation - is that a problem? Insulation - is it work having that foam stuff around them? Access - is there a reason I should make it more accessible? Anything else?

Many thanks,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are heating pipes just box them in. You shouldn't have any issues with condensation. Just be careful not to nail/screw through them.

Comment: Many thanks, they'll be boxed in at the weekend. Sharp things will be kept well clear :)